# SQL error on phpBB

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, phpbb

I get this error when trying to update the profile in ucp

```
SQL ERROR [ mysql4 ]

Unknown column 'see_porn_cat' in 'field list' [1054]

SQL

UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_icq = '', user_aim = '', user_msnm = '', user_yim = '', user_jabber = '', user_website = 'http://footballbb.org', user_from = '', user_occ = '', user_interests = '', user_notify_type = '0', see_porn_cat = NULL, user_custom_title = 'U JELLY?' WHERE user_id = 9086

BACKTRACE

FILE: includes/db/mysql.php
LINE: 175
CALL: dbal->sql_error()

FILE: includes/ucp/ucp_profile.php
LINE: 423
CALL: dbal_mysql->sql_query()

FILE: includes/functions_module.php
LINE: 507
CALL: ucp_profile->main()

FILE: ucp.php
LINE: 327
CALL: p_master->load_active()
```

I have made some changes there in the past,but I'm sure that I removed the database and the code that's related to the changes I made.
Can you tell me where to look for anything related to that error ?  :roll:

Comment: lol no I removed that from the style. and removed the column from the table. now I have to remove some code which is making that error appear,but not sure where..

Comment: Why not search for the column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table does not contain the column `see_porn_cat`

So you need to use this query

```
UPDATE phpbb_users SET user_icq = '', user_aim = '', user_msnm = '', user_yim = '', user_jabber = '', user_website = 'http://footballbb.org', user_from = '', user_occ = '', user_interests = '', user_notify_type = '0', user_custom_title = 'U JELLY?' WHERE user_id = 9086
```

Comment: Yes,I deleted that column because I don't need it anymore. but I guess I should've deleted something in the code as well. not sure where though. :\

Comment: but your query contains the column name. you need to remove it from your query.

Comment: I know. But do you have any idea where do I find that ? which file at least ?

Comment: check file `includes/ucp/ucp_profile.php` and line number near 423